# composite of holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f: \Bbb D \to \Bbb D$(unit disk) be a holomorphic function with $f(0)=0, |f'(0)|<1$. For $f_n=f \circ \cdots\circ f$ (n times), show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(z)$ converges uniformly on compact subsets in $\Bbb D$.

I tried Schwarz lemma so that $|f(z)|\le |z|$, and I tried to use Weierstrass M test, but I don't know how $f_n$ is bounded. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to use effectively the assumptions, especially $|f^\prime (0)|<1$.
We first show the following:
For any $r\, (0<r<1)$, there is a constant $c<1$ ($c$ depends on $r$) such that the inequality
$ |f(z)|\le c|z|   $
holds for every $z\, (|z|\le r)$.
Proof.
If there exists no such a constant $c$, there is a sequence $\{z_n\}$ with $|z_n|\le r$ such that
$|f(z_n)|> (1-1/n)|z_n|$ , $n=1, 2, ...$ .
We may suppose without loss of generality that $\{z_n\} $ converges to a point $z_0\,(|z_0|\le r)$.
If $z_0=0$, we have $|f^\prime(0)|\ge 1$, which contradicts the assumption $|f^\prime(0)|<1$.
If $z_0\ne 0$, we have $|f(z_0)|\ge |z_0|$. Then 
Schwarz lemma leads to $f(z)=\varepsilon z$ with $|\varepsilon|=1$, which contradicts $|f^\prime(0)|<1$.

Thus we have $$|f(z)|< cr,\, |f_2(z)|< c|f(z)|< c^2r,\, ...\, ,\, |f_n(z)|< c^nr,\, ...$$
on  compact subsets $\{|z|\le r\} \subset \mathbb{D}$ and we can use Weierstrass M test.

Comment: It looks close to the answer, but I don't know why $z_0=0$ implies $|f'(0)| \ge 1$. Also $|f(z)|<c|z|$ is not true for $z=0$.

Comment: We have $|f(z_n)|/|z_n|>1-1/n$ from $|f(z_n)|>(1-1/n)|z_n|$. Tending $n$ to $\infty $, we get $|f^\prime(0)|\ge 1$. Two errors in inequalities are fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: there are $0 < r_1 < r_2 < 1$ such that $f$ maps $r_2 \mathbb D$ into $r_1 \mathbb D$.  The Arzela-Ascoli theorem will also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly an answer but
to prove $f_n$ is bounded note that $f_n(0)=0$ also $f_n'(0)=f'(f_{n-1}(0))f'_{n-1}(0)=f'(0)f'_{n-1}(0)$. Now using induction we can show that $|f'_n(0)| < 1$. So we can use Schwarz inequality on these functions as well.